# Join two select in mysq

Tags: mysql

I intend to join two selects, but I don't intend to use union or union all, because I intend to add columns to the right side of the query. I will explain the two queries.

```
SELECT N_utente, Ano, Mes, Farmacia
FROM raddb.Areceber
where N_utente <> '0' AND Farmacia <> '0.00' AND Mes = '1'
```

returns the following:

```
N_utente, Ano, Mes8, Farmacia8
'602',  '2022', '9', '16.23'
```

Then I have the second query:

```
SELECT N_utente, Ano, Mes, Cabeleireiro
FROM raddb.Areceber
where N_utente <> '0' AND Cabeleireiro <> '0.00' AND Mes = '1'
```

returns the following:

```
N_utente, Ano, Mes9, Cabeleireiro9
'716',  '2022', '10', '16.00'
```

Now I want to join the two queries, where I have the following result:

```
N_utente, Ano, Mes8, Farmacia8, Mes9, Cabeleireiro9
'602',  '2022', '9', '16.23',   '10', '16.00'
```

Is it possible to combine the two queries like this? union does not allow to join the two queries in this way

Comment: Try `JOIN` the second query with the first where the `ON` condition is just `TRUE`

Comment: @Sean Anglim Can you put an example of how I put the true condition?

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE'S if your version is 8.0 and more:

You can check your version: SELECT VERSION();

Then Code :

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT N_utente, Ano, Mes, Farmacia
FROM Areceber
where N_utente <> '0' AND Farmacia <> '0.00' AND Mes = '1')
,cte2 AS (SELECT N_utente, Ano, Mes, Cabeleireiro
FROM Areceber
where N_utente <> '0' AND Cabeleireiro <> '0.00' AND Mes = '1')
SELECT cte1.N_utente, cte1.Ano, cte1.Mes AS Mes8, cte1.Farmacia AS Farmacia, cte2.mes AS Mes9, cte2.Cabeleireiro AS Cabeleireiro9
FROM cte1 JOIN cte2 ON cte1.Ano = cte.Ano;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your WHERE condition

```sql
SELECT N_utente, Ano, Mes, IF(Farmacia <> '0.00', Farmacia, Cabeleireiro) AS something
FROM raddb.Areceber
where N_utente <> '0' AND (Farmacia <> '0.00' OR Cabeleireiro <> '0.00') AND Mes = '1'
```